# Gcc Makefile .elf file failed

Tags: gcc, makefile, stm32

I try to use main.cpp with my source code. I think everthing is fine but I get error, I have exactly same makefile with different project I didnt have error. But I open the new project with Cubemx and try to use some cpp settings in makefile so it didint work.

I get below erorr :

```
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:195: recipe for target 'build/stm32f4_FlashflagTest.elf' failed
make: *** [build/stm32f4_FlashflagTest.elf] Error 1
```

How can I solve this ?
And this is my makefile:

```
    ##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.5.2] date: [Fri Jul 24 10:23:57 TRT 2020]
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = stm32f4_FlashflagTest


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Src/stm32f4xx_it.c \
Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_can.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c \
Src/system_stm32f4xx.c \

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32f429xx.s

#CPP_SOURCES
CPP_SOURCES = \
Src/main.cpp \

# A_SOURCES
# A_SOURCES = $(wildcard Middlewares/STM32_Safety_STL/Src/*.a)

#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
CXX = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)g++

else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
CXX = $(PREFIX)g++

endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S

#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS =

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32F429xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES =

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IInc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include



# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"

CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32F429VITx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys
LIBDIR =
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning
# LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(CPP_SOURCES)))

# list of *.a objects
OBJECTS += $(A_SOURCES)
vpath %.a $(sort $(dir $(A_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.cpp=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.a Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AA) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
#    $(AA) $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(A_SOURCES) -o $@
#    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)

#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)
###################################################
#               Install & Program
###################################################
install:build/$(TARGET).bin
    @echo "$(CURDIR)/bin/$(TARGET).bin"
#   /usr/local/bin/st-flash erase
    /usr/local/bin/st-flash --reset write "$(CURDIR)/build/$(TARGET).bin" 0x8000000

#
# ###################################################
# #                       etags
# ###################################################
# etags:
#   find $(ST_STD_LIB_PATH) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
#   find $(CMSIS_LIB_PATH) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
#   find $(FOC_LIB) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
#   find . -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append

# *** EOF ***

# deneme:
#
#   echo $(OBJECTS)
#   echo $(BUILD_DIR)
    #  echo $(A_SOURCES)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem
But I dont know why it works corretly. could anybody explain this?

I use the -specs=nosys.specs instead of -specs=nano.specs
I change this line :

```
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning
```

with:

```
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nosys.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning
```